# Cannot override doInBackground-method (asyncTask)

Tags: java, android-asynctask

why I cannot override the doInBackground-method in my class?

```
public class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {


@Override

protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override

protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {



    String email = args[2];
    String password = args[1];
    String name= args[0];

    ArrayList params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    if(email.length()>0)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);


    return json;

}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Error:
class AttemptLogin must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...) in 'AsyncTask'

It works if I change the parameter of the doInBackground to (Object[]). Why I cannot pass String values?

Comment: Those 3 paramters in `<>`  things are kind of important. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to something like this

```
public class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject> {
...
```

You have to tell AsyncTask the class of your return type otherwise it defaults to object